# STM32 signal level issues

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, signal-integrity

I have some weird signal issues and I'm not sure if its my layout or if my chip (STM32F405) is just broken.

I'm toggling a port every ~1ms, but my scope says it's only outputting 900mV. There is a spike at the beginning of roughly 2.9V, but it quickly goes down. The noise following the drop does imitate the signal on VCAP1 though, which is odd.

The pin is two away from VCAP1, the trace directly beside VCAP1 also picks up the signal from VCAP1. My question is whether I need to redesign some aspect of the signal or if it is just a chip gone bad? I'm a bit puzzled as to why the signal fails to reach the normal signal level.

Here the signal in question:

[image: Broken signal]

Closeup of the spike:

[image]

Compared to VCAP1:

[image: VCAP1]

And here the respective routing. Signal is on 47, VCAP1 on 49. 50 is VCC and 48 another signal. VCC also shows the Pattern of VCAP1, so there seems to be some coupling. 48 also has this pattern, also at 900mV even though it is turned off.
[image: Routing]

And here the schematic. The signal path in question is from U3:PB10 to U11:P6.
[image: Schematic]

Comment: What's it connected to? Could there be contention?

Comment: It's connected to an isolator (MAX14850ASE+T) and two of the other ports connected to that chip work just fine. It's just the two beside vcap that refuse to work properly

Comment: It's connected to one of the bidirectional ports, I suspect the isolator is pulling it down. Can you add a weak pull up between pins 11 and 16 of the isolator?

Comment: There's a note about this in the bidirectional channels section of the datasheet https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX14850-1515080.pdf

Comment: Huh.. I'll try that tomorrow evening. Must've missed that one ^^'

Comment: Indeed. That seems to fix the issue, although there is still a 50ns dip in the signal which does not matter though for my signal speeds. The second IO channel does not need one though, probably some shenanigans in the RS485 chip. If you create an answer I'll accept it.